# connectionTimeout undefined in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am getting this error:

> setconnectiontimeout undefined for okhttpclient
>   setreadtimeout undefined for okhttpclient

Here is my import code and function..

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient.Builder;


OkHttpClient httpParameters = new OkHttpClient();
httpParameters.setConnectionTimeout (3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //timeout connection
httpParameters.setReadTimeout(3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //timeout socket
```

What should I do when get this error undefined? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think method is `setConnectTimeout` not `setConnectionTimeout`. Which version you are using of OkHTTP.

Comment: Use `OkHttpClient client  = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build()`

Comment: i am currently use okhttp3.9.1...i had try setConnectiontimeout but the error still there..